# Storing URL string with special characters in NSString in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, url, freebase

I am trying to use [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) in an iOS app, and queries are constructed using URL's. The URL's contain multiple special characters ({}, :) but I would like to be able to use the URL strings so I can download the data from Freebase.

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=[{"type":"/music/album","name":null,"artist":{"id":"/en/bob_dylan"},"limit":3}]&cursor

When loading the URL in Safari, the browser actually converts that string to this: https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%5B%7B%22type%22:%22/music/album%22,%22name%22:null,%22artist%22:%7B%22id%22:%22/en/bob_dylan%22%7D,%22limit%22:3%7D%5D&cursor

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method on an `NSString` to add the percent escapes for you.

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. Not sure if you tried, but that works for the second URL. The second URL I posted works fine, but it's the first one I need.